# Using Jasmine with Ionic is there a way to mock/stub a static namespace function call?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, ionic2

I'm new to this space so bear with me. I am working in an Ionic 2 project so it is using Angular 2, Typescript, and Jasmine for unit testing. I'm trying to write a unit test right now for a weird case. I have a third-party library that I import in a component with an import at the top like `import * as thirdparty from "thirdparty-library"` and later my component makes a call like `thirdparty.setup(someStuff, someMoreStuff, anotherFunc)`.

Really what I want to do is have a mock `thirdparty` with its own fake `anotherFunc`that I pass from the unit test. So is there a way to pass something in the constructor and have it override this `thirdparty` namespace? Thank you in advance

Comment: No. That's why we've got DI in Angular.

Comment: @estus Huh? This is Angular, I just don't know how to "DI a namespace" if that's the right word for it. So please let me know, thanks. :)

Comment: You can't DI a namespace. If you need to use third party library, you have to wrap it into a service and use it only through DI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions being first class citizens, can be assigned new values. So if you want, you can always just do something like

```
let ogFunct;

beforeEach(() => {
  ogFunt = thirdparty.setup;
  thirdparty.setup = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    console.log(`arg1 - arg2 - arg2`)
  }
});

afterEach(() => {
  thirdparty.setup = ogFunct;
});
```

Sometimes library type definitions will make the function read-only. In which case, you can't assign anything. Maybe in this case the better option would be to just abstract the third-party calls into a service. And just mock the service. You might even consider doing this anyway. Personally I think it is better design then using the third-party directly in the component.

Comment: Thanks...I have taken the latter route you suggested and made a provider I could mock.